# How to run php scripts in React

Tags: javascript, python

iam trying to run a python script ,when a button is clicked in the app

solution found: I made a function and converted scripts into js format and called the function when button is clicked

Comment: As it is, this question is lacking any relevant details that would help us to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

server.py

```
import flask
import subprocess

app = flask.Flask("__main__")

@app.route("/run_it")
def run_something():
    subprocess.Popen("/path/to/executable")
    return "JOB started"


app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=8000)
```

client.html

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.113:8000/run_it">Click Here To Run your JOB</a>
```

is one way you might do it (where 192.168.1.113 is the ip address of the raspberry pi)

Comment: socket.on("ActivateTrigger2", () =>{ // server is receiving from send trigger button
  console.info("Trigger function working");
  const data = {
   Sender: 5,
   Private: false,
   EventType: "Button",
   StringParam: "B2_SWB",
   Param1: 1,
   Param2: -1
  };
  const baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.88:8082";
  putRequest(
   baseUrl + "/abk/events/client_event",
   data,
  );
 });